# What is the name and part number of this round decorative gold part?

Tags: piece-information

What is the name or part# of this round piece? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a [Wheel Wagon - Ornate Huge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15744&idColor=115#T=C&C=115).

You can tell from the link, but as you explicitly ask, I guess I should say that the part number is 15744.